# Last item in array not displayed from within loop

Tags: awk

The last item of an array doesn't print properly from within a loop

While learning the shell text filters, I made a little awk script that formats the output of a CSV file by providing the heading inline.

A wrapper shell script is invoked from the command-line, and all it really does is wrap the awk script and pass along an argument as variable `regex`, which is the search string.

The script stores the fields of the first record (`NR==1`) into array `heading`. Once the record containing the search string `regex` is found within the body of the CSV file, the script concatenates the heading to the appropriate value.

csv.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

awk -f ~/Scripts/csv.awk -v "regex=$1" $2
```

csv.awk:

```
BEGIN {FS=",";}
NR==1 { 
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { 
    heading[i]=$i; 
  } 
}
NR>1 {
  if ($0 ~ regex) {
    for (i=1; i<=length(heading); i++) {
      if(length($i) > 0) { 
        print(heading[i] ": " $i)
      } 
    }
    print("")
  }
}
```

### Demonstration

ships.csv:

```
name,country,displacement,length,beam,commissioned
Yamato,Japan,65027,256,38.9,16 December 1941
USS Enterprise,United States of America,19800,251.4,33.4,12 May 1938
Bismarck,Germany,41700,251,36,24 August 1940
HMS Dreadnought,United Kingdom,18120,160.6,25,2 December 1906
USS Iowa,United States of America,46000,270.43,32.97,22 February 1943
HMS Vanguard,United Kingdom,45200,248.2,32.9,12 May 1946
```

#### Invocation

`$ csv Enterprise ships.csv`

#### Expected output

```
name: USS Enterprise
country: United States of America
displacement: 19800
length: 251.4
beam: 33.4
commissioned: 12 May 1938
```

#### Terminal output:

```
name: USS Enterprise
country: United States of America
displacement: 19800
length: 251.4
beam: 33.4
: 12 May 1938
```

On my Linux computer (Manjaro), the output is very similar. But actually, if I pipe the output to `pbcopy` on my Mac the heading does show up after pasting:

```
name: USS Enterprise
country: United States of America
displacement: 19800
length: 251.4
beam: 33.4
commissioned
: 12 May 1938
```

Comment: `i<=length(heading)` looks fishy.. I guess you need  `i<=NF`

Comment: Your data file has DOS-style `\r\n` line endings. The word "commissioned" is actually `commissioned\r`, so the cursor is sent to the start of line before the colon and the value are printed.

Comment: Glenn I can't vote for your comment

Comment: If `length(heading)` is not equal to `NF` then you have a problem so `i<=length(heading)` could be written as simply `i<=NF`. Also `if(length($i) > 0)` is equivalent to just writing `if ($i!="")`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Glenn's comment, could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=",";}
{gsub(/\r/,"")}
NR==1 { 
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { 
    heading[i]=$i; 
  } 
}
NR>1 {
  if ($0 ~ regex) {
    for (i=1; i<=length(heading); i++) {
      if(length($i) > 0) { 
        print(heading[i] ": " $i)
      } 
    }
    print("")
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing an array to `length` function is [less portable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-differences-between-gawk-and-awk).

If you suspect a messy csv file where your headers may not match up to the actual columns, then, a portable option would be to store the count of the total columns in the beginning and then reuse it like below :

```
NR==1 { 
  headercount=NF; # store the count
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { 
    heading[i]=$i; 
  } 
}
NR>1 {
  if ($0 ~ regex) {
    for (i=1; i<=headercount; i++) { #Use the count
      if(length($i) > 0) {
        print(heading[i] ": " $i)
      }
    }
    print("")
  }
}
```

Also, if you have to deal with dos-style file endings, you may change your script to :

```
#!/bin/bash
dos2unix -q "$2" # This makes sure that the input file has unix style file endings
awk -f ./csv.awk -v "regex=$1" $2
```

**Test**

```
$ ./csv.sh HMS ships.csv 
name: HMS Dreadnought
country: United Kingdom
displacement: 18120
length: 160.6
beam: 25
commissioned: 2 December 1906

name: HMS Vanguard
country: United Kingdom
displacement: 45200
length: 248.2
beam: 32.9
commissioned: 12 May 1946
```

If your headers are tampered so that they don't have, say, commissioned column, this would seamlessly work in that scenario too.

**Test**

```
$ ./csv.sh HMS ships.csv 
name: HMS Dreadnought
country: United Kingdom
displacement: 18120
length: 160.6
beam: 25

name: HMS Vanguard
country: United Kingdom
displacement: 45200
length: 248.2
beam: 32.9
```

Comment: I didn't want the loop to produce formatted output if there was no header to concatenate. So if it was a messy CSV file where only 3 headers were provided but the data had 5 columns... But awk's length function appears to understand the context and gives the correct output for array length.

Comment: @JasperZanjani I have modified the answer to reflect the issue mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55695039/last-item-in-array-not-displayed-from-within-loop#comment98073110_55695039) comment.